# Handle Submit in Material UI with Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I want to Ask about the use of **Material UI** in **Next Js**.

I'm here to try one of the Login **Material UI** templates, but when I make the handle on Submit, it adds query params in my Url.

From.

> localhost:3000/auth/login

Becomes.

> localhost:3000/auth/login?email=&password

Which makes it difficult for me to debug Results from Submit, because this page immediately reloads the page.

Here I split it into several files.

1. Components.
2. Containers
3. Pages

Inside Components.

```js
import React from 'react'

// * Material UI
import { Container, CssBaseline, Avatar, Typography, TextField, Button, Box } from '@material-ui/core'
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined'
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress'

// * Component
import Footer from '@components/v2/Login/Footer'

// * Jss
import { loginJss } from '@client/public/assets/jss/Login'

export default function Body ({
  onSubmit = () => {},
  isBusy = false,
  errorMessage = ''
}) {
  const classes = loginJss()

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log(event)
    onSubmit(event)
  }

  return (
    <Container component='main' maxWidth='xs'>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component='h1' variant='h5'>
            Sign In
        </Typography>
        <form
          className={classes.form}
          noValidate
          autoComplete='off'
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <TextField
            variant='outlined'
            margin='normal'
            required
            fullWidth
            id='email'
            label='Email'
            name='email'
            autoComplete='email'
          />
          <TextField
            variant='outlined'
            margin='normal'
            required
            fullWidth
            name='password'
            label='password'
            type='password'
            id='password'
            autoComplete='current-password'
          />
          <Button
            type='submit'
            fullWidth
            variant='contained'
            disabled={isBusy}
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            { isBusy ? <CircularProgress /> : 'Sign In' }
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt='8'>
        <Footer />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Inside Containers.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Body from '@components/v2/Login/Body'

export default class login extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isBusy: false,
      errorMessage: ''
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubmit (params) {
    console.log(params)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    if (this.props.isLogin) {
      console.log('LoggedIn')
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Body
        errorMessage={this.state.errorMessage}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Inside Page.

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'

// * Containers
import Login from '@containers/v2/login'

export default class login extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Login />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there a way to block adding a param query to the url when on Submit?

Thank you.

Comment: You shoud disable the default behaviour of a form submit. You can simply add ```event.preventDefault()``` to your ```handleSubmit``` function.  `const handleSubmit = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault(); console.log(event)
    onSubmit(event)
  }`

Comment: Okay, I understand. Does this apply to other Forms when I create a CRUD?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake I made. This is my first time using react. After I find out, I have to add `event.preventDefault()` when on submit or on click.

Comment: yes..every time you use native `<form>` you should disable the default behaviour

Comment: Thank you @dna. Now it's working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the mistake I made. This is my first time using react. After I find out, I have to add `event.preventDefault()` when on submit or on click. Thank you all.